# connecting android app to mysql trough web service using soap

Tags: android, mysql, asp.net, web-services, ksoap

I am creating an app which places the order. and i have created the web service which is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace myservice
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public void order()
        {
            string fname, lname, email, shippingno, city, product, price;

        }
    }
}
```

But i don't know how to enter the values in web methods

This is my mainActivity.java:

```java
package com.example.orderform;


import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
    private final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/websd/Service1.asmx";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
    private String TAG = "PGGURU";
    private static String fname;
    private static String lname;
    private static String email;
    private static String shippingno;
    private static String city;
    private static String product;
    private static String price;
    TextView show;
    EditText e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        e4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        e5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        e6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        e7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        Button b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                 //Call execute 
                 task.execute();
            }
        });
    }
    public void adddata(){

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        //Property which holds input parameters
        PropertyInfo a1 = new PropertyInfo();
        //Set Name
        a1.setName("First Name");
        //Set Value
        a1.setValue(e1);
        //Set dataType
        a1.setType(String.class);
        //Add the property to request object
        request.addProperty(a1);

    }
    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            HelloWorld();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
        }

    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and this is my layout

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="First Name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Last Name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Shipping No" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="City" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/state_arrays"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:prompt="@string/state_prompt" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Product" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" >

                <requestFocus />    
                </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Price" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" >

                <requestFocus />    
                </EditText>            


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Submit" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.orderform"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I want to know that how my data will go to webservice and then to the database. help me or send me a best tutorial link. Waiting for your help
thanks!